adding data in state variable it get added twice from API key
when i am fetching data from API and storing it in state array (this.state.articles) only in componentDidMount function it is getting concatenate 2-3 times.
updateNews = async () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&sortBy=popularity&apiKey="MyApikey"&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.state.pageSize}`;
  let data = await fetch(url);
  data = await data.json();
  this.setState({
    articles: this.state.articles.concat(data.articles),
    totalarticles: data.totalResults,
  });
  console.log("data=>", data);
  this.setState({ loading: false });
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.updateNews();
};


Possible duplicate of Why componentDidMount gets called multiple times in react.js & redux?
